# Simple differentiation issue

Tags: derivatives

I'm blanking on the simplest thing ever:

$$L = x$$
$$\frac{dL}{dx} = 1$$

But if I do:

$$x = m + n$$
$$\frac{dL}{dx} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial m}\frac{\partial m}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial L}{\partial n}\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}$$

$$\frac{dL}{dx} = (1)(1) + (1)(1)$$
$$\frac{dL}{dx} = 2$$

Yeah, this is embarrassing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, you assume that $$\frac{\partial m}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial n}{\partial x} = 1$$

However in reality $$\frac{\partial m}{\partial x} = 1 - \frac{\partial n}{\partial x}$$

And vice versa. So now the result checks out.

Comment: D'oh.  Slaps forehead.  Thank you.